# Criar trigger dentro de uma procedure?

Tags: sql-server

Gostaria de saber se é possível criar uma Trigger dentro de uma procedure? (SQL SERVER)

O motivo é que eu dropo a tabela que está com a trigger no final do dia, e depois recrio ela com uma procedure, e após da criação da tabela, ele recriar a trigger também....

Answer (score 3):

Sim você pode fazer sim conforme segue no exemplo da própria microsoft:

```
USE tempdb;
SELECT ProductNumber, ListPrice, Color
INTO Product
FROM AdventureWorks2008.Production.Product
GO
CREATE PROC sprocCreateDynamicTrigger
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)=
    'CREATE TRIGGER trgProduct
    on Product for INSERT
    AS
    DECLARE @InsProd varchar(32) 
    SELECT @insProd = ''TRIGGER: '' + ProductNumber FROM inserted
    PRINT @InsProd'
  EXEC sp_executeSQL @SQL
END
GO 
-- Execute stored procedure to create trigger
EXEC sprocCreateDynamicTrigger
GO
INSERT Product VALUES ('Alpha Romeo 2011', 40000, 'Blue')
GO
-- TRIGGER: Alpha Romeo 2011


DROP  PROC sprocCreateDynamicTrigger
DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.Product
```

Comment: Vlw cara, bom saber do sp_executeSQL!